# How to find the center of the minimal bounding circle for three (and more) shapes?

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles

Suppose there are two rectangles with a common side (Figure A, blue line) or two quadrangles that do not have common points (Figure B, blue line).

It is required to construct the mininal bourding circle for two figures (case A, B).

**Attempt**, build two shapes to a rectangle, then find the intersection point of the diagonals. This point will be the circle center.

**Question**. Now to find the center of the minimal bounding circle for three (and more) shapes?

[image]

**Edit** after the fantasie's comment.
[image: Case A]

[image: Case B]

Comment: It seems that there are smaller circles yet still covers these two rectangles in case A and B.

Comment: @fantasie, could you please discribe your point of view?

Comment: I conjecture that the minimal circumscribed circle of arbitrary many $n$-gons are minimal circumscribed circle of a triangle whose vertices are points from the vertices of these $n$-gons. If this is true, then a systematic process to find out the minimal circumscribed circle is to exhaust these combination of vertices.

Comment: In fact, I find your question kind of questionable. By wikipedia, the circumscribed circle of a polygon is the circle that passes *all* of its vertices. In your cases, the shapes doesn’t necessarily have a circumscribed circle. Perhaps you meant minimal bounding circle instead?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I need to find a minimal bounding circle.

Comment: I don't think the conjecture of @fantasie is true even for $n=1$. Consider the rhombus with vertices at $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$, $(n,0)$ and $(-n,0)$ for some large $n$. The circumscribed circle of the first three points won't go through the fourth point, the circumscribed circle through the last three points will be much larger than the circle of radius $n$ centered at the origin, which does contain all four points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find convex hull, in O(n)log(n) of initial n points at vertices of initial polygons via https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan

Find minimum bounding circle of convex hull using Nimrod Megiddo's or Welzl's algorithm in O(n) of n points on convex hull.

Find center of the bounding circle. (trivial)

Comment: The complexity should be $O(n \cdot \log(n))$